# How to train a word embedding representation with gensim fasttext wrapper?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, gensim, word-embedding, fasttext

I would like to train my own word embeddings with fastext. However, after following the tutorial I can not manage to do it properly. So far I tried:

In:

```
from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText as FT_gensim

# Set file names for train and test data
corpus = df['sentences'].values.tolist()

model_gensim = FT_gensim(size=100)

# build the vocabulary
model_gensim.build_vocab(sentences=corpus)
model_gensim
```

Out:

```
<gensim.models.fasttext.FastText at 0x7f6087cc70f0>
```

In:

```
# train the model
model_gensim.train(
    sentences = corpus, 
    epochs = model_gensim.epochs,
    total_examples = model_gensim.corpus_count, 
    total_words = model_gensim.corpus_total_words
)

print(model_gensim)
```

Out:

```
FastText(vocab=107, size=100, alpha=0.025)
```

However, when I try to look in a vocabulary words:

```
print('return' in model_gensim.wv.vocab)
```

I get `False`, even the word is present in the sentences I am passing to the fast text model. Also, when I check the most similar words to return I am getting characters:

```
model_gensim.most_similar("return")

[('R', 0.15871645510196686),
 ('2', 0.08545402437448502),
 ('i', 0.08142799884080887),
 ('b', 0.07969795912504196),
 ('a', 0.05666942521929741),
 ('w', 0.03705815598368645),
 ('c', 0.032348938286304474),
 ('y', 0.0319858118891716),
 ('o', 0.027745068073272705),
 ('p', 0.026891689747571945)]
```

What is the correct way of using gensim's fasttext wrapper?

Comment: for me, it seems like there's some problem with `df['sentences']`, How you are converting sentences into tokens and saving it for them in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gensim `FastText` class doesn't take plain strings as its training texts. It expects lists-of-words, instead. If you pass plain strings, they will look like lists-of-single-characters, and you'll get a stunted vocabulary like you're seeing.

Tokenize each item of your `corpus` into a list-of-word-tokens and you'll get closer-to-expected results. One super-simple way to do this might just be:

```
corpus = [s.split() for s in corpus]
```

But, usually you'd want to do other things to properly tokenize plain-text as well – perhaps case-flatten, or do something else with punctuation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to looking in vocabulary words, the vocabulary words should be written to a text file in order to become visible from that text file. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48553559/10872307) could be helpful for you:

```
with open("vocab.txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as vocab_out:
    for word in model_gensim.wv.vocab:
        vocab_out.write(word + "\n")
```